# Sending/receiving .txt file from Android to PC, not whole file is sent

Tags: c#, java

I'm trying to make an Android app that sends a .txt file to a Windows Forms application on my computer. The problem is that not the whole file gets sent (I haven't been able to find out whether the problem is on the sending or receiving side). I only get a random part from somewhere in the middle of the .txt file to the receiving side. What am I doing wrong? The strange thing is that it has worked perfectly a few times, but now I'm never getting the beginning or the end of the file.

The Android app is written in Java, and the Windows Forms app is written in C#. filepath is the name of my file. What is the problem here?

**Code for Android app (sending file)**

```
//create new byte array with the same length as the file that is to be sent

byte[] array = new byte[(int) filepath.length()];

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
//use bufferedInputStream to read to end of file
bufferedInputStream.read(array, 0, array.length);
//create objects for InputStream and OutputStream
//and send the data in array to the server via socket
OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(array, 0, array.length);
```

**Code for Windows Forms app (receiving file)**

```
TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

byte[] message = new byte[65535];
int bytesRead;

clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path + dt);
//message has been received
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));  
fs.Write(message, 0, bytesRead);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: bytesRead will be 0, when you use it. This can't be the reason for your problem, but indicates that you missed an important part of your code.

Comment: It's not a good idea to load the entire file into memory. It's also not a good idea to have a fixed buffer size.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov He's using the binary input to output a string using ASCII.

Comment: @renman You need to provide more information. For example, `(int) filepath.length()` is `filePath` a string?

Comment: @ByteBlast filepath is a File. Shouldn't I be able to use the length of it?

Comment: That will give you the length of the file path in letters! Not the file.

Comment: @ByteBlast - so how can i get the size of the file? Is that even possible? The length of my filepath is about 50 characters, but when debugging filepath.length() could be as big as 5000, so i assumed that that was the length of the file

Comment: @renman Oh. Excuse me then. Please update the post with the variable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the complete array to your memory and sending it to an outputstream afterwards, you could do read/write at the same time, and just use a "small" buffer byte array. Something like this:

```
public boolean copyStream(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream){
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024]; //Whatever buffersize you want to use.

    try {
        int read;
        while ((read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1){
            bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Log, retry, cancel, whatever
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

on the receiving side you should do the same: Write a portion of bytes as you receive them and not store them completly into the memory befor using.

This might not fix your issue, but is something you should improve anyway.